# C# DropDownlist default value -1 but displaying incorrectly

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu

I am running into an extremely frustrating problem I'm hoping everyone can help with.

I have two sets of Dropdownlists; The first one is populated from a database call, and it is simply a unique list of clients.  The second one is a list of servicers; and it should be FILTERED by the results of the first Dropdownlist.

Note the main problem seems to be that the first drop down list result of "DropdownListClient.SelectedIndex.ToString()"  is showing a value of -1.   however when teh web page is launched the drop down list only has two options.

`Value       List Description 
0           Green Tree
1           Chase`

So why is the DEFAULT selected value of the Dropdownlist equal to -1?   I can't seem to find anything that would set the default to whatever value is displayed in the dropdown list.

my code behind looks like this..

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = User.Identity.Name;
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
Documenation_ClientProject.SelectParameters.Add("Personlookup",User.Identity.Name);
Documenation_ClientProject.SelectCommand = "SELECT distinct Clientname FROM [FileReviewProject] where personid=@Personlookup";
Label2.Text = DropDownListClient.SelectedIndex.ToString();
/*shows a -1 but should show a 0 (since the displayed result in the first    drop down list is the 0 value of green Tree*/
Documenation_ServicerProject.SelectParameters.Add("ServDef",    DropDownListClient.Text);
Documenation_ServicerProject.SelectCommand = "SELECT distinct LoanServicer    FROM [FileReviewProject] where clientname=@ServDef";

        }                         
    }
```

And my asp.net page looks like...

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="Documenation_ClientProject" runat="server"
 ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DEVSQLCATConnection%>"> 
</asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="Documenation_ServicerProject" runat="server"
 ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DEVSQLCATConnection%>"> 
</asp:SqlDataSource>


<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListClient" runat="server" DataSourceID="Documenation_ClientProject" DataTextField="ClientName" DataValueField="ClientName" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownListClient_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownServicer" runat="server" DataSourceID="Documenation_ServicerProject" DataTextField="LoanServicer" DataValueField="LoanServicer">
  </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Usually, the default value for the dropdowns/comboboxes in .NET is no selection (= -1). For example: with the elements 1, 2, 3 it doesn't show 1, but a blank space (which is translated into -1 for the index). "Correcting" this is easy: just select the index you want when the application is started. For example: `DropdownListClient.SelectedIndex = 0;`.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing has been selected yet so `DropdownListClient.SelectedIndex` is of course -1, set your index to 0 `DropdownListClient.SelectedIndex = 0` before you set `Label2.Text` and you should be fine.